# Convergence of square root operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Let $Q_n$ and $Q$ be compact positive and symmetric operators. Let $A_n = {Q_n}^{\frac12}$ and $A=Q^{\frac12}$. Given $Q_n$ converges to $Q$ w.r.t. operator norm. Does $A_n$ converges to $A$? Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress towards a solution yourself?

Comment: I tried pretty hard to prove it, but did not succeed. So now I tend to think it may be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch: The square root is [operator monotone](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Operator_monotone_function). Now, if $Q_n\rightarrow Q$, then, given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$,
$$
(Q-\epsilon I)_+\leq Q_n\leq Q+\epsilon I.
$$
It follows that 
$$
(Q-\epsilon I)_+^{1/2}\leq Q_n^{1/2}\leq (Q+\epsilon I)^{1/2}.
$$
It therefore suffices to show that
$$
(Q\pm\epsilon I)_+^{1/2}\rightarrow Q^{1/2},
$$
in norm, as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. But this convergence we can show by working in an orthonormal eigenbasis for $Q$!

Here is a sketch of a more elementary proof, with wider applicability: Let $f\in C(\mathbb R)$ be any continuous function (for the square root, put $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$). Since $\|Q_n\|\leq \|Q-Q_n\|+\|Q\|$, it suffices to consider $f$ restricted to $[0,2\|Q\|]$ for $n$ large enough. Then we can pick a polynomial $p$ which approximates $f$ uniformly, say $\|p-f\|_{[0,2\|Q\|]}<\epsilon$, and thus
\begin{align*}
\|f(Q)-f(Q_n)\|&\leq\|f(Q)-p(Q)\|+\|p(Q)-p(Q_n)\|+\|p(Q_n)-f(Q_n)\|\\
&\leq 2\epsilon+ \|p(Q)-p(Q_n)\|,
\end{align*}
whenever $n$ is large enough, say $n\geq N$. But it is not hard to show that $p(Q_n)\rightarrow p(Q)$ in norm!

Comment: Thanks! and by any chance you are aware of some references that has this problem? coz this seems a very standard problem for operator theory textbooks. In that case, I think I better cite some references (I am working on a note that needs this result).

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm sure it must be treated somewhere. You don't need the compactness condition, and it is not clear to me whether you can generalize from the square root to a general continuous function. Maybe you will have luck if you look up sources on operator monotone functions.